# Extracting specific data from xml using Notepad++

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I have a xml response with a structure ( e.g groups > subgroups > child records ) and repeats several thousand times with different values with each one.

I want to only grab subgroups whose 9 digit serial number field matches what I provide and extract them into its own file.  When extracting the subgroups, it would also bring the group with it.  I was hoping such a task would be possible using notepad++ and possibly through the use of regex, but not sure how I would go about in doing this.

Comment: No. Use an XML parser and XPath. Notepad++ with regex is not the right tool for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with notepad++ specifically.   For my solution to work it work it would need to support multi-line regular expressions and advanced regular expression syntax (non-greedy matching).  Not all text editors that support regular expressions will do either.

I would start and end with the outer tag that you want`\<subgroup\>\<\/subgroup\>` escaping the special characters.  To capture what is in between, I would use non-greedy matching `\<subgroup\>\.*?<\/subgroup\>`.  Then I would add the specific serial number you are interested in `\<subgroup\>\.*?123456789.*?<\/subgroup\>`.

If you want to find some of multiple serial numbers here use something like

```
\<subgroup\>\.*?(123456789|987654321|678912345).*?<\/subgroup\>
```

Comment: In my case multiple serial numbers are involved and I was thinking if it was possible to somehow add these in a comma delimited type list for notepad ++ to extract only the groups with the serial numbers in the list.

Comment: Edited my answer to include finding a list of serial numbers